# How to check whether an object is a descendant of a given class in Haxe?

Tags: oop, haxe

I would like to be able to check whether an object is a descendant of a given class, but it does not seem possible.

I would like to port the following code from C#:

```cs
public virtual Systems Add(ISystem system) {
    var initializeSystem = system as IInitializeSystem;
    if(initializeSystem != null) {
        _initializeSystems.Add(initializeSystem);
    }

    var executeSystem = system as IExecuteSystem;
    if(executeSystem != null) {
        _executeSystems.Add(executeSystem);
    }

    var cleanupSystem = system as ICleanupSystem;
    if(cleanupSystem != null) {
        _cleanupSystems.Add(cleanupSystem);
    }

    var tearDownSystem = system as ITearDownSystem;
    if(tearDownSystem != null) {
        _tearDownSystems.Add(tearDownSystem);
    }

    return this;
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve the same functionality in Haxe?
Note, that an object might be descendant of several classes I am testing for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`Std.is()`](http://api.haxe.org/Std.html#is)?

```
if (Std.is(system, IInitializeSystem)) {
    _initializeSystems.add(cast system);
}

if (Std.is(system, IExecuteSystem)) {
    _executeSystems.add(cast system);
}

// etc
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I need. Just curious: would it be possible to achieve the same result during compilation using macros? As the type of the object is known compile-time. And number of classes I am testing against is constant.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve by using macros here. Generate the `add()` method and the `_initializeSystems` / `_executeSystems` lists?

Comment: The logic behind this function (Systems.add(system: ISystem)) is the following: depending on whether 'system' is descendant of a possible ISystemXyz classes (limited number) -- add it to a corresponding container. If 'system' is a subclass of multiple ISystemXyz it gets added to multiple containers.
When I call 'systems.add(mySystem)' I know type of mySystem during compilation, hence would like to be able to determine where 'mySystem' is being added to during compilation and inline this function, so no ifs during runtime. Whilst 'Std.is' (if I understand correctly) does it during runtime.

Comment: Yeah, you could probably do that if `add()` was an expression macro. However, that's really a separate question. :) And yes, `Std.is()` is at runtime.